# How do you get a DatePicker from a DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have a activity that is popping up a android.app.DatePickerDialog.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(this, startDateSetListener, start_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), start_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), start_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

I want to get at the DatePicker View from the DatePickerDialog so that I can set the min and max dates. The API reference says that there is a method getDatePicker and that has been there since API 1 but it is invalid, my ide doesn't like it.

```
DatePicker picker = dialog.getDatePicker();
```

"The method getDatePicker() is undefined for the type DatePickerDialog"

Any one know what API was the method created in or how I can get to the DatePicker to edit min/max dates?

I am using API 7, Platform 2.1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Despite that getter method only being available in Honeycomb and above (as dmon correctly pointed out), you can still fairly easily get access to the `DatePicker` object encapsulated by the `DatePickerDialog` using reflection. It'll look something like this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = ... // create dialog
Field mDatePickerField = dialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDatePicker");
mDatePickerField.setAccessible(true);
DatePicker mDatePickerInstance = (DatePicker) mDatePickerField.get(dialog);
```

From this point on, you have a reference to the internal `DatePicker` object and you should be able to change it to your own liking. Please do beware of any obvious typos, as I entered this directly into the browser.

Comment: Good answer.  Unfortunately the get and set max on date picker are API 11 also...

Comment: Bummer, I hadn't looked at those yet. Unfortunately, while browsing through the source of `DatePicker` for  2.1-update1, the min/max date logic is completely absent. I suppose you could create your own extension of `DatePicker` to deal with that, and inject it into the `DatePickerDialog` (or use a custom dialog), but it seems like an awful lot of work for something quite minor.

Answer (score 4):

You misread, it's only available since API 11:

"public DatePicker getDatePicker () Since: API Level 11". Look *[closely](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#getDatePicker%28%29)*.