# unable to go fast date and time in android calender picker?

Tags: android, datetime, calendar

In my project i have 2 text fields

1. date field
2. time field

When I click the date button I need to show android date piker but the piker don't  goes to already pasted date.

In my date picker I am handled the date piker to don't goes to pasted date fallowing way

```
   private void disable(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

    if (year > maxYear)
        view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

    if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
        view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

    if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
        view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

    if (year < minYear)
        view.updateDate(minYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear)
        view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, dayOfMonth);

    if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
        view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

}
```

but I am unable to fix the time piker to don't goes to already fast time

Here 2 scenarios are happening:

1. user selected the tomorrow date and select past time
2. user select today time( but not pastime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this also

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

datePicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 200000);
```

Also see these link

[Android datepicker min max date before api level 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836679/android-datepicker-min-max-date-before-api-level-11)

[How to set minimum DatePicker date to current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date)