# Setting a specific date in datePickerdialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I have setMaxDate in datepickerdialog. Its working well, but the minimum value in year segment is 1980. How can i set that value to, say 1900.
my code is :

```
DatePickerDialog dp=new DatePickerDialog(getParent(),datesetListener,day,month,year);
dp.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeinMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `dp.setMinDate(new Date(1900,1,1));`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the underlying DatePicker from a DatePickerDialog (by simply calling getDatePicker()) and set its bounds using:

[setMinDate(long minDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29)

[setMaxDate(long maxDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29)

Where the argument is the usual number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in the default time zone. You'll still have to calculate these values of course, but that should be trivial to do with the Calendar class: just pass current date and add or substract x years from that.

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813311/set-min-and-max-date-in-my-date-picker-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android)

Sample code

```
        Date min = new Date(2013-1900, 4, 21);
        DatePicker p = getDatePicker();
        p.setMinDate(min.getTime());
```

Comment: tried this but its setting the min year to 2014 and max to 2036, not wha is xpected