# How to Hide Past dates and restrict user to select future dates only

Tags: android, android-datepicker

How to Hide past dates on DatePicker dialog ? I don't wanna allow user to select past dates

What would be the best way ? if i want to restrict user to select future dates only !

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        .................................................
        editDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });   

    }

     @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DATE:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        dateTime.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        editDate.setText(dateFormatter
                                .format(dateTime.getTime()));
                    }
                }, dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                   dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                   dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            return null;
     }

}
```

Comment: Why the bounty? Did you not like the setMinDate method?

Comment: have a look to [seMinDate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20813342/2591002) method.

Comment: `setMinDate()` should be enough. You could use `setMinDate(new Date())` and the minimum date will be today

Answer (score 10):

You have to use [setMinDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) for minimum date and you can also use [setMaxDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) if you want to set maximum date.

Here is sample code for `SetMinDate` for `DatePickerDialog`.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DATE:

            DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dateTime.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    editDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                }
            }, dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            Calendar mCalendarMinimum = Calendar.getInstance();
            mCalendarMinimum.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
            mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mCalendarMinimum.getTimeInMillis());
            return mDatePickerDialog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [setMinDate (long minDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) to achieve your goal. Doc says:

```
Sets the minimal date supported by this NumberPicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.
```

Answer (score 2):

U can try this code in your switch case

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(AddTaskActivity.this,
                    myDateListener, year, month, day);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            dpd.show();
```

Where myDateListener is following code

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        showDate(arg1, arg2 + 1, arg3);
    }
};
```

and showDate() is the method to display the date in textView
Here is the code for showDate()

```
 public void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

    String day1 = String.valueOf(day);
    String month1 = String.valueOf(month);



   String  s2 = day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year;

    Log.e("date", s2);
    Cal.setText(s2);
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with one line of code:

```
datePicker.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

This way, the Date Picker will show only dates from the current time and forward.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
this.datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // (picker is a DatePicker)
    this.datePicker.setMinDate(this.calendar.getTimeInMillis());
} else {
    final int minYear = this.calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int minMonth = this.calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int minDay = this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    this.datePicker.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay,
            new OnDateChangedListener() {

                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int month, int day) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, month, day);

                    if (calendar.after(newDate)) {
                        view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                    }
                }
            });
    Log.w(TAG, "API Level < 11 so not restricting date range...");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)