# Dialog DatePicker android 2.x start year

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have datepickerdialog like this:

```
birthDateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddGrave.this, R.style.datePickerStyle, birthDateDialogListener, 
birthCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
birthCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
birthCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
birthDateDialog.show();
```

and style:

```
<style name="datePickerStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:endYear">2200</item>
    <item name="android:startYear">1000</item>
</style>
```

It works properly on android 4.x, but on android 2.2/2.3 range of the year is still 1900-2100. How can i change that range?

Comment: Yes, values-v11, values v-14 with the sames lines code

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is because `setMaxDate` and `setMinDate` were not introduced until API 11. These xml attributes might rely on these methods. I'm speculating here, since the documentation does not list a min API level for these xml attributes. [Here is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836679/android-datepicker-min-max-date-before-api-level-11) to `setMaxDate` programmatically.

Comment: But I need to do it with API < 11. So are there any suggestions?

Comment: The link provided will work with API < 11. It just has to be done programmatically rather than in XML.

Comment: All answers works only for set Min and Max date in range 1900-2100 in Android 2.x. I'm trying to use https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker now. I'll know how it goes.

Comment: This library (github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) won't works. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: That's odd. Do they work for the native DatePicker? If so, there's an issue with that 3rd party library and you should file a bug so they can fix it.