# setMaxDate to DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

Hi I implemented a **DatePickerDialog** but I want to set range, I found *setMinDate* and *setMaxDate*, but I don't know how to put values. I want to set the calendar for a user of min age 18 and max age 100; I think it's about calculations into milliseconds.

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, this, year, month, day);
dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(max);
return dpd;
```

I don't know what value I have to put to max to do 2016 - 18.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android

Comment: @Juvi Yes I looked at, but it get the actual date as max

Comment: new Date().getTime() returns the current date, so i assume you want to set your own date. Just create new Date object and set it values, and than set it as maxDate...

Comment: @Juvi I wan't that the user is not younger than 18 years old, soI have to set the max to now - 18

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad Look my edit please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android datepicker min max date before api level 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836679/android-datepicker-min-max-date-before-api-level-11)

Comment: please visit this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, to set maximum date and minimum date from current date.

```
Calendar minCal = Calendar.getInstance();
minCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, minCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 100);
Calendar maxCal = Calendar.getInstance();
maxCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, maxCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 18);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minCal.getTimeInMillis());
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: I don't get the good ranges it have to be between 1916 to 1998 (min age is 18 max age is 100)

Comment: Good thanks, do you know how I show the full date, like if I put 1/1/1993 I want to have 01/01/1993

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need:

```
            final Calendar maxc = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = maxc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            maxc.set(Calendar.YEAR,year-18);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxc.getTimeInMillis());

            final Calendar minc = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = minc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            minc.set(Calendar.YEAR,year-100);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minc.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: it will not work for age validation. Please edit your answer .